# SQL Server 2008 Filestream Logon Failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream

When using(attempting) the SqlFileStream object, I am receiving an error

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
```

I'm a little perplexed by this.

- I'm using SQL Server authentication in the connection string
- I can write to the table in question except for the FILESTREAM column
- The SQLSERVER service is running under an account that has full privileges to the physical filestream directory
- The filestream directory does not have READONLY flagged.

Am I required to use a 'Windows Integrated Security' connection string to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filestream doesn't work with SQL Authentication. From [FILESTREAM Storage in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109%28SQL.100%29.aspx):

> **Security**
>
> There are two security requirements
>   for using the FILESTREAM feature.
>   Firstly, **SQL Server must be configured
>   for integrated security**. Secondly, if
>   remote access will be used, then the
>   SMB port (445) must be enabled through
>   any firewall systems.

See also [How It Works: File Streams Requires Integrated Security (Windows Authentication)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/04/10/how-it-works-file-streams-requires-integrated-security-windows-authentication.aspx).